# MATLAB plotting $\log(h)$ vs. $\log(e(h))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

So I have the initial value problems below. From a previous part, I have already confirmed that $v(t)$ is a solution to the the problem above it. Now I am left to write a MATLAB code that plots $\log(h)$ vs $\log(e(h))$ and that verifies that the Euler Method's approximation is first order by computing the error $e(h)$.

I understand that we must have $e(h) = O(h)≈C·h^p$ for some constant $C$. Which then means $e(h) = p·\log(h)+C_1$, if I am correct. But I am confused on how I should first approach the problem.

Any hints or referrals to tutorials, I looked online but didn't find anything helpful. Thank you.

\begin{align}
y'(t)&=-y(t)+t+1,\qquad t\in[0,1],\\
y(0)&=1,\\
\\
v(t)&=e^{-t}+t
\end{align}

Comment: You do already have the code for the Euler method? Make it a function that takes $h$ as parameter. Account for the possibility that $1$ is not a multiple of $h$, either by modifying $h$ to the next fit or by adapting the step length of the last step. Please report this state in the question. -- Matlab plot gives the option for loglog plots, you do not have to take the logarithm manually.

Comment: Yes, I do! Thanks for the help, it makes sense now.